# Stopping users modifying items being updated by devops in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops

Are there any settings that will prevent users of Visual Studio (2019) from modifying files while a devops operation completes. For example when you switch branches, it is possible to open and modify files that have the code from the prior branch and then to save it after the switch has taken place which is causing errors.

Is there a way to force devops to work in the foreground (i.e. prevent user activity until it has finished), to ensure the code stays safe?